# How do I constrain connected vertices to share a single edge?

Tags: graphviz, vertex, direction, edges, digraphs

Because of the way that information is being generated, I results that look like this:

```
digraph "A" {
  "a1" -> "a2";
  "a2" -> "a1";
  "a1" -> "a2";
  "a2" -> "a1";
}
```

[image]

What I would prefer to see, is:

```
digraph "A" {
  "a1" -> "a2"[dir=both];
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to tell the entire digraph to merge edges,
and create bidirectional edges where possible?

I'd like to keep the data as generated, but add a few lines to create the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially what [`concentrate`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:concentrate) is for.

Simply add the following line to your graph, at the beginning or the end:

```
concentrate=true
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answerd by marapet the answer to your case is `concentrate`. However there is a completely different answer to a slightly different problem which I want to add here for completeness. If you want to merge directed edges only you may use the keyword `strict`.

```
strict digraph "A" {
  "a1" -> "a2";
  "a2" -> "a1";
  "a1" -> "a2";
  "a2" -> "a1";
}
```

[image]